# How to point a domain (fx. GoDaddy), to AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cname

I am trying to link a domain (from godaddy) to a S3 bucket with a static website (Amazon AWS).

I tried few variants:

1. Changing nameservers
2. Adding 2 CName records from an issued SSL certificate by AWS

Official AWS docs give an examply by making an Amplify App - but is there a way without it?

I have tried few tutorials, and changed CName a few times - and now I am not sure what are the default values too (there is no revert to default button).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help. But the way I did it is by creating a Cloudfront distribution and linking it to the S3 bucket with static content (I'm pretty sure this is the proper way to do it).

But first you need to create a wildcard certificate (like `*.your-domain.com`). If you already have a certificate you can skip this step.

So when you create a Cloudfront distribution, you can supply the certificate you got in the previous step.

Cheers

Comment: Ah I forgot I have also done this step. I have a cloudfront linked. But my domain still does not show my webpage on aws. However I see on the bottom part of the chrome window that it acesses the aws api but then still show godaddy default page

Comment: Make sure you have set correct permissions for the S3 bucket (I think you need it to be public) and make sure your CNAME record is correct and points to your Cloudfront distribution.

Follow this article if you need to, it is pretty clear
https://dev.to/namuny/integrating-aws-cloudfront-with-third-party-domain-provider-2ce3